How do I replace curved trim on a semicircle half-turn staircase landing
Well you know it is time for home improvement when your new pup chews the staircase spindles.
Link to Pictures
Two questions:

Is this a sound approach to replacing the spindles:  Keep bannister, cut spindles and pull out both ends, install simple iron balusters.
What would be the easiest aesthetically pleasing solution to fixing the curved trim which has cracked.  I want to ensure this doesn’t happen again.

Thanks for the advice!  I am loving this community.

I believe those balusters are still made. The split wood can be finessed back in, with some glue, pressure and a bit of filler. I am leaving this as a comment since you mentioned about replacing with metal

Thanks, Jack.  Given my pup’s chewing habit and in order to freshen up the look, I was thinking of going with metal.

Please embed the pics directly so that when you decide to clear up space on your Google Drive, this question still has useful info for others.

How large will the whole scope of work be, is it just the curve section only, or is there a full set with stairs? A pic or pics of the whole rail would be better, the detail shots are good, but what you ask, depending on how long the run is, could be tricky at best, or shabby at worst.
